# Return a Array to class Variable

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?

$calendar = new MyCalendar();
echo $calendar->show();

class MyCalendar {     
    private $curBirthday=array();

    public function show() {
        ...
        $this->$curBirthday=$this->_loadBirthday();
        ...
    }

    private function _loadBirthday() {
        // SQL STUFF
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT ...  ");     
        $return_arr = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
            ...

            array_push($return_arr,$row_array);                         
        }
        return $return_arr;
    }   
}
?>
```

Can anyone explain why my code will not work?

the fault must be here:
$this->$curBirthday=$this->_loadBirthday();

If I let show the data of _loadBirthday(), they are correct.
Write to the classes variable seems impossible.

what am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$this->$curBirthday=$this->_loadBirthday();
```

to this:

```
$this->curBirthday=$this->_loadBirthday();
```

More information on this site: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
You were referring to the property with the name that is inside $curBirthday, which does not exist in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much! Some times are too many trees in the wood... <3